# import sol file from github error: File Nod Found

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Hi I have a problem about import sol file from github.

I use remix online in remix.ethereum.org.

But I can not import the sol file from github and I don't know why??

Can everyone help me?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an update in Remix caused the issue. Please also follow here: https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/696

As a workaround I added it manually as a import .sol file.

Example: import "./oraclize.sol";

Comment: it seems fit it! I can import sol from github. Thanks for you help:)